# Count Relational Table Rows

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm trying to count the number of rows in a relational table `many to many`, but always returns the wrong value. When it is 1, always returns 2.

PS: All models and foreign keys in mysql are configured correctly.

Comments Table:

```
id  |  name
10      Comment Test
```

Users Table:

```
id  |  name
20     User Test
```

Likes (Comment/User) Many to Many:

```
user_id  |  comment_id
20          10
```

Code:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select='*, COUNT(likes.id) AS count_likes'; // I believe the error is in the use of COUNT (likes.id).
$criteria->with=array('likes'=>array('on'=>'user_id=20'));
$model = Comments::model()->findByPk($_GET['id'], $criteria);

// Return Wrong Value
echo $model->count_likes; // Return 2 where should be 1. (I need to use this case)
echo count($model->likes); // Return right value 1.
```

Comment: Can you print the complete query and post it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Statistical Query](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/fr/database.arr#statistical-query), e.g. :

In your Comments model :

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        // ...

        // I assume your relation table's name is "likes"
        'likes'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Users', 'likes(comment_id, user_id)'),
        'likesCount'=>array(self::STAT, 'Users', 'likes(comment_id, user_id)'),

        // ...
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning on selecting from the LIKES table and group by them by their userid and comment id?
If so, you can use **GROUP BY**
Please take a look at the SQLFiddle here

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc29b8/1/0 


`SELECT uid, cid, COUNT(likes.cid) FROM likes GROUP BY uid, cid`

Comment: I need to use Comments table with relation in this case. If I echo `count($model->likes)` it returns right value `1`.

Comment: can you use `DISTINCT` so make it as `DISTINCT user_id, comment_id,COUNT(likes.id) AS count_likes GROUP BY user_id, comment_id` ?